# PHP array - `array_splice` issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am working with PHP array to store the comma separated values of product Ids and then in turn use them to show as recent seen products.

Implementation is as below:

```
$product_data = array();
$array_ids_a_display = array();   
$check_status = array();
$array_check= array();
$_COOKIE['Pr'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Then i am Taking the last point of the stored string

```
$array_check = explode(',',substr($_COOKIE['IdProduto'],0,-1));
```

Now, i check of products are enabled then store them into one other array

```
foreach($array_check as $id_a_checar){
    $check_status = $this->model->getProduct($id_a_checar);
    if($check_status['status']){ // If status is 1
        $array_ids_a_display[$contprods++] = $id_a_checar;
    }
}

if($s['limit']>count($array_ids_a_display)){ 
    //If the number of valid products < number of products of module
    $s['limit'] = count($array_ids_a_display);  
      //will show,then reconfigures the number of products that will show
  }   
}
```

where `$s['limit']` comes from backend , let us say `6` to limit the number of products.

Now, i will reverse the array to get latest visited product at first place like as

```
$last_ended = array_reverse($array_ids_a_display);
array_splice($last_ended,0,(int)$s['limit']);
foreach ($last_ended as $result) {
    $product_data[$result] = $this->product->getProduct($result);
}
```

> Now here comes the problem, as i am only getting **3** products in **$product_data** array but is shall get **6** products.

I hope that there is issue with `array_splice` because if i will comment array_splice then i am getting all stores products in cookies as result.
Mysql query is working very fine.

**Please advice how to get latest 6 values from array**

Comment: if I were you the first thing I would do is some echo debugging to see where your data is getting lost

Comment: I have written that my data has problems with array_splice

Comment: Till array reverse i am getting all 8 IDs

Comment: Your _data_ is what you need to show.  Nobody knows what your _data_ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
$last_ended = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
$last_ended = array_reverse($last_ended);
//here is what you missed:
$last_ended = array_splice($last_ended, 0, 6);

print_r($last_ended);
//returns Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 7 [2] => 6 [3] => 5 [4] => 4 [5] => 3 )
```

You need to **assign** your `$last_ended` var into `array_splice` result.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Get the last 6 entries of an array...
$arr = array(
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8
);

$entries = array_splice($arr, -6);
// returns [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$maxResultLength = 6;
$someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
$startIndex = (count($someArray) >= $maxResultLength) ? count($someArray) - $maxResultLength : 0;
$lastSixElements = array_slice($someArray, $startIndex, $maxResultLength);
```

or

```
$maxResultLength = 6;
$someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
$lastSixElements = array_splice($someArray, -6);
```